# Setup a Docker container for dotnet core application with database connection ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, odbc

My Docker file is like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80                         
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80   
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Info.dll"]

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8
COPY VC_redist.x64.exe c:/ \
     msodbcsql.msi c:/
RUN c:\\VC_redist.x64.exe /install /passive /norestart 
RUN msiexec.exe /i C:\\msodbcsql.msi /norestart /qn /quiet /passive 
IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES
```

And my Docker compose file is like this

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
   build:
   context: ./
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "80:80"
 volumes:
   - ./:/app
 environment:
   DATABASE_PARAMS: Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
  Server};server=000.000.0.0\\sql2017;database=info;uid=0;pwd=0
 links:
    - "db"
  depends_on:
    - "db"
 db:
   image: christianacca/mssql-server-windows-express
 ports:
  - "1433:1433"
 environment:
   ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

I am new to docker and .NET. Can anyone help me to run this inside the Docker? When I run this command

```
docker build -t info
```

it builds properly.

```
docker run -p 8080:80 info
```

when I run this command whole my VS Ccode gets stuck. And Docker also hangs.

Comment: Well `mssql-server-windows-express` is likely going to become a problem for you because Microsoft stopped supporting SQL Server on Windows containers earlier this year. Ref: [Update- Beta program for SQL Server on Windows container is suspended](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639). You might want to switch to `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` with `-e "MSSQL_PID=Express"` instead, Ref: [Official images for Microsoft SQL Server on Linux for Docker Engine](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server).

Comment: so i need to implement this in linux container right? do you know how to install ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server on linux container